# javascript email regexp issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow `_` inside the email.

but the regexp i have just filter this.

html,

```
<input id="external_email_input" maxlength="85" type="text">
    <button id='email'>Send</button>
```

js,

```
 $("#email").click(function(){
        var email = $("#external_email_input").val();
        if(!validateEmail(email)){
            alert("wrong format!!");
        }else{
            alert("correct!!");
        }
    });    




function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/rRnwb/1/

if i put test@test_test.com

it returns false

how can i allow `_` as a condition in here?

Comment: Just put it in the required character class. And validating email by regex is not always a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<input type="email" />`. Remove all JavaScript. Problem solved.

Comment: `<input type="email" />` works in IE8. It just won't have validation. But that's okay because validation should be server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying validation to include underscore (_) as suggested by Jerry in comments solves the problem.

Validation function:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"_]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rRnwb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your code was :

[image]

There is no `_` to satisfy your input mail id after `@` symbol.

So , you can use :

```
(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|((\w+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/rRnwb/3/)**

**Explanation :**
[image]